# How to hide child elements of a div in different width?

Tags: html, css, width, plyr

I want to hide control icons and the other elements of plyr in different width, like native html5 audio player.

I try @media query in css but it just work for different window width not the plyr (parent div) width..

Help me please...

[image]

Comment: I assume you have the default HTML 5 audio controls enabled yes? Disable them and create your own controls with HTML and CSS and/or JS in order to control layout and style. There are plenty of audio player tutorials out there that show you how to accomplish this.

Comment: No. In the gif i show the difference between native audio player and my audio player (plyr). I want to make my plyr behave like native

Comment: Plyr is not for mine-> https://plyr.io/ @dale